# что делает __attribute__(__noreturn__) в си

Tags: c, атрибуты, define

Я нашёл в книге Linux API выражение

```
#define NORETURN __attribute__((__noreturn__))
```

может мне кто-то объяснить как это работает?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/TbFAJLVE это макрос для инициализации ошибок, но не понимаю что делает __attribute__

Comment: @Spatz - я вижу очень часто Ваши комментарии с очереди проверок, которые прикрываются ботом, но очень часто они немного бессмысленные.

Answer (score 3):

Есть некоторые функции, с которых программа уже не возвращается. Например, abort или longjump. Такие функции обычно и помечены подобным атрибутом, что бы компилятор (а также и анализаторы кода) знали о этой особенности и не задавали лишних вопросов, а также могли чуточку оптимальное/правильнее написать код.

А Ваш дефайн - это распространённая практика - дело в том, что большинство таких атрибутов сильно зависят от компилятора. И что бы постоянно не писать кучу #ifdef, вводят вот такие "мета атрибуты", а уже система сборки (или в  одном хедере) подставляют правильные значения для выбранного компилятора/среды.